# how to reach dipper divs inside <span> tag using python crawler?

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

the body tag has a `<span>` tag. There are many other divs inside the span tag. I want to go dipper but when I trying this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/artfido/'
data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
result = soup.body.span
print (result)
```

the result was just this:

```
<span id="react-root"></span>
```

How can I reach to divs inside the span tag?

Can we parse the `<span>` tag? Is it possible? If yes so why I'm not able to parse the span?

By using this:

```
    result = soup.body.span.contents
```

The output was:

```
[]
```

Comment: you need to give us the url so we can try your code

Comment: can't test it, I have a restrictive proxy... but you should do `soup = BeautifulSoup( data.read(), 'html.parser') `

Comment: it's weird that you got a result, or maybe the function is different from python2

Comment: Why?! There is no need to use `data.read()`. right?!

Comment: in python 2 at least yes, because data is just an object. From the doc: `If all went well, a file-like object is returned`

Comment: aha, I'm using python 3.4

Comment: I understood that (had to adapt your code)

Comment: from the python 3 doc: `This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods from the urllib.response module`

Comment: Any idea? any solution?

Comment: @Whitefret, what does `data.read()` do here? an other friend pointed to this before if you read above comments... There is no need for that, right? I just don't know how to reach to the divs inside the `span` tag.

Comment: well sorry but I can't help then, because I can't get the same result with this code (except the changes from version 3 to 2). it's unlikely you only get an empty span...

Comment: @Whitefret, what did you got with your own code? What was the result? Could you reach the divs inside the span tag?

Comment: I got the proxy so I had to download the page to make it works, but I get all elements in `<span id="react-root"></span>`. Another difference but it should't change much, is that I use lxml and not html.parser

Comment: @Whitefret, can you post the code you used to test here please if its ok? Just want to try that.

Comment: I can post something similar using your code, but the only change I can think of is about the read function. anyway, will post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110376/discussion-between-whitefret-and-niloofar).

Answer (score 0):

As talked in comments, urlopen(url) returns a file like object, which means that you need to read from it if you want to get what's inside it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/artfido/'
data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.read(), 'html.parser')
result = soup.body.span
print (result)
```

The code I used for my python 2.7 setup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/artfido/'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.read(), 'lxml')
result = soup.body.span
print result
```

**EDIT**
for future reference, if you want something more simple for handling the url, there is a package called [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/master/) . In this case, it is similar but I find it easier to understand.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/artfido/'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
result = soup.body.span
print result
```

Comment: by testing the first and the third one, the output was the same as what I had faced with. And couldn't test the second code because of my python version.

Comment: I've updated my question a little, please see it. Is `<span>` tag the problem?! because this tag is the only tag I could not parse.

Comment: @niloofar ok we got a bit misunderstandings. I will edit with some code to only have the span tag

Comment: what do you mean you cannot parse it?

Comment: @niloofar Do you get the page when you print the soup?

Comment: Just the <head> part and in the <body> part, just this line `<span id="react-root"></span>` and some <script> tag under the span tag.